# Create folder in APPDATA on Windows Vista/7

Tags: wpf, permissions, installation, installshield, appdata

I have made an application in WPF and it has user profiles, not related to Windows user profiles. It's quite a simple thing, but I need to store those profile files somewhere. As I read, the preffered folders are Appdata, common application data etc. For me, even Documents will do the trick (it's a school project, those things don't really matter that much). My problem is how to make the a for the profiles folder in some of those places, becouse I do not have elevated permissions with my application? I know how to get to them, but not read/write.

I suppose that the installer is ment for that, and I am using InstallShield Limited Edition with Visual Studio 2010, but I don't know how to configure it to make a folder when installing.

Will unsuficient permissions make problems when I succeed in making an app folder, and want to write in it, or they not protected this way?

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During an installation you can set permissions on your folder in AppData. For example, you can set full permissions for **Everyone**. This way your application should have write access in the folder.

In your case you can set permissions through the InstallShield support. Another solution is to use [XCACLS.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) as a custom action.

Comment: You never want to do this without asking the user first. Even then you really don't want to do this.

Comment: I now realize my choice of words was not very good. He can set permissions on his folder from AppData, not on AppData directly. I don't think you need to ask the user about this. If it's your custom folder, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: If it's your custom folder, you already have permissions to write there. Changing permissions should be done by the user and only by the user.

Answer (score 3):

I would just check if the files exist (using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`, and create a subfolder and write there from your app if not. You almost always have permissions to write there.

An installer pretty much has permissions to write everywhere, because the user has to grant them before running it. However, I don't think the installer is the right place to generate these files. You will have to overwrite them later anyway.

Comment: Already done that, the application does not have permissions for it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. When creating the installation, in the Shortcuts/Folders segment of the InstallShield configuration, right-clicking somewhere in the tree opens a context menu where it is possible to make APPDATA and similar folders visible, and then configure what you need there i.e creating folders for an application to use. Quite an unintuitive approach, hence it works.

I've already tried it out, writing inside a folder in the APPDATA does not need any special permissions.

This solves my problem. Thanks to all of you :) .